# table relationship to many different tables

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a system that involves uploads. Now these uploads need to be attached to one of a manner of things eg. a message, a contract, a project

Is it okay to have one table for attachments then link them to these types - the caveat being that it needs to be linked to an individual id from each of these types

eg. in the attachment table

type - links to a table with the list of message contract etc

id. - an id # of what ever id for the type so if the type is message then it would refer to message.id if it was a contract it would refer to contract.id

but then there's no foreign key checks? But it seems odd to have to do foreign keys eg.

```
type
message_id (FK)
contract_id (FK)
project_id (FK)
```

Edit: there's a few more tables than 3 more like 5-6 perhaps more in future too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend:

1. A table for attachment (attachment_id + other columns necessary for your attachment)
2. For each possible types (message, contract, project), you will have a relationship table.

Example:

- MessageAttachmentTable: message_id (FK), attachment_id (FK)
- ContractAttachmentTable: contract_id (FK), attachment_id (FK)

That way, you can have all the database integrity constraints with no unused columns.

Comment: this seems like complicating things unnecessarily

Answer (score 0):

Three NULLable fields with foreign keys to the respective tables is in my opinion the most sensible approach.

Moreover, if you have three foreign key fields, you don't even have to store the "type", since it is determined by the foreign key field which is not NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I didn't mention there could be a few more columns 3 was only an example I did like this solution but upon thinking I don't think it will scale as well as LMC's

Comment: Where does this improvement come from?  You'll have a table with two columns to make a link, instead of just one column in an existing table.  Moreover, if you have 100 attachments, you will have 200 rows, 100 in the attachment table, and another 100 spread over the link tables (instead of just 100 rows in the attachment table).

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for the reply - I'm still quite new to mysql - if I had that table with 200 rows.. how do I find the non null FK without a ridiculous select?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question; but it's just `WHERE message_id IS NOT NULL`.  However, I don't know why you would want to do this.  Generally, you'll need to fetch the attachments of a particular record, as in `WHERE messages_id = XXXX` or `WHERE  contract_id = XXXX`.

Comment: I believe the fundamental issue with multliple nullable FK in a table is that it creates ambiguity in the data model (multiple ways to represent the same data concept).  Also, there is no easy way to use database constraints to restrict only exactly one FK to be non-NULL, or use cascading delete to keep the table intact.

Comment: Hi Andreas, of course that would be the select - must have been really tired last night! Well I wanted the ability to select all the attachments of a particular type which is why I wanted that Select.

Comment: In light of that - I was thinking perhaps the multiple nullables was the way to go.. but then after reading up on cascading delete i'm back to thinking multiple tables would possibly be the better way to go? I really appreciate the help! Thanks